What are possible returned types of authentication.getPrincipal() in Sping Security?
I traced following codes in debug mode and I find that the returned type of authentication.getPrincipal() is Jwt.
public static OidcUser getLoginUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser) {
        return (OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    }
    return null;
}

I searched all implementations of Authentication interface and find that apart from OAuth2AuthenticationToken class and OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken class, the returned type in remaining implementing classes is Object.
Part of codes shown:
public class OAuth2AuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    private final OAuth2User principal;
    @Override
    public OAuth2User getPrincipal() {
    return this.principal;
    }
}

public class OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    private OAuth2User principal;
    @Override
    public OAuth2User getPrincipal() {
    return this.principal;
    }
}

Why is the returned type Jwt? Apart from Jwt, what are other possible returned types?

The Spring Security documentation explains why after a successful authentication, the Authentication is a JwtAuthenticationToken and has a principal that is the Jwt.
